# WatchOS Using ObservableObject in Conditional in View Causing Runtime Error

Tags: swift, swiftui, state, watchos, tabview

I use an `ObservableObject` to keep the state of whether a user is subscribed to my app or not, and based on the subscription status, show different views. This worked fine prior to Xcode 13 and WatchOS 8, but now this is causing a runtime error of `runtime: SwiftUI: Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update.` And, the binding does not update per the error. This occurs on both Xcode 13.1 and 13.2b2

This code below reproduces the error:

```
struct MultiPageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var subscribed = SubscribedModel.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        if subscribed.value {
            TabView {
                ViewOne()
                ViewTwo()
                ViewThree()
                ToggleView()
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        } else {
            TabView {
                ViewOne()
                ToggleView()
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct ToggleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var subscribed = SubscribedModel()

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $subscribed.value) {
            Text("Subscribed")
        }
    }
}

class SubscribedModel: ObservableObject {
    public static let shared = SubscribedModel.shared
    
    @Published var value: Bool = false
}
```

I am only listing `ViewOne` for brevity, but `ViewTwo` and `ViewThree` are the same with different text:

```
struct ViewOne: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View One")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

If you navigate to the `ToggleView()`, and switch the toggle, the error pops immediately. Any suggestions to fix this?

Update per @LoremIpsum comment:

```
struct MultiPageView: View {
    @StateObject var subscribed = SubscribedModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        if subscribed.value {
            TabView {
                ViewOne()
                ViewTwo()
                ViewThree()
                ToggleView(subscribed: $subscribed.value)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        } else {
            TabView {
                ViewOne()
                ToggleView(subscribed: $subscribed.value)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct ToggleView: View {
    @Binding var subscribed: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $subscribed) {
            Text("Subscribed")
        }
    }
}
```

It is now switching between the `TabViews`, but the error still remains, and is showing up immediately. Deleted DerivedData and cleaned build folder. Any thoughts?

I will add that this same basic code is running fine on iOS 15. It is just WatchOS that is popping the error.

Comment: The toggle model is not the same as the multi page view. Also if u initialize the observed object in a view you should use state object instead. But in this case just don’t initialize in the toggle get it as a parameter from the multi page view

Comment: I updated the code a bit, as I was using a `.shared` singleton, and not a new instance. However, I changed it around per your suggestion, and only a slight improvement. The error still remains.

Comment: What line is giving the error?

Comment: That has been the crazy part. It isn't associated with any line for either the actual project or the MRE. I have a thread trace, but I was having problems Symbolicating it. I put a question up about getting the ASLR Slide with otool, but didn't get any response to that. I got this far by process of elimination, and the MRE confirmed that it was to do with the conditional in the view being changed outside of the view. The `Runtime Error` breakpoint unhelpfully stops at `@main`, and the trace isn't helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issue for a long time, and this is still happening on **Xcode 13.2.1**.

Seems to be an issue with `TabView` on **watchOS**, because if you replace the TabView for another View the error is gone.

The solution is to use the initialiser for `TabView` with a `selection` value: [init(selection:content:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview/init(selection:content:))

### 1 Define a property for selection

```swift
@State private var selection = 0
```

### 2 Update TabView

#### From

```swift
TabView {
    // content
}
```

#### To

```swift
TabView(selection: $selection) {
    // content
}
```

---

Updating your code would look like this:

```swift
struct MultiPageView: View {
    @StateObject var subscribed = SubscribedModel()
    @State private var selection = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        if subscribed.value {
            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                ViewOne()
                ViewTwo()
                ViewThree()
                ToggleView(subscribed: $subscribed.value)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        } else {
            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                ViewOne()
                ToggleView(subscribed: $subscribed.value)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

Basically just defining a `@State` property for `TabView.selection`, and using it on both your TabViews (using separated properties would also work).

Comment: How did you EVER come across this solution? Works like a charm! I will take it back and see how it works in the production app, but thank you!

Comment: genius, error goes away. Thank you for solution